# How to reduce image quality in the form of byte array

Tags: java, image, image-processing, compression

I have an RGB image take the form of byte array, obtained by using getRGBPixels method of RobotPeer class. **How can i reduce this image quality**

I have used QuickLZ to compress this image, but it still too big to transfer over network.

Comment: QuickLZ is a lossless compression algorithm.  Have you considered using anything **lossy**?  What about JPEG?

Comment: @rayryeng, I have used Robot.captureScreenShot method which return a BufferedImage. Then i used ImageIO to convert it to JPEG with lower quality and size. But this way take too much time.

Comment: What is `Robot`? Is it a separate library you are using?

Comment: Rotbot is a class inside java.awt package, more detail here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: Can you give me some more insight on what you are doing? Why do you want to transfer screenshots over a network?  If you give me more information I can suggest alternatives.

Comment: You could convert the RGB to YCbCr color space, and do chroma subsampling similar to what JPEG compression does. It will reduce quality, and probably make the image compress better.

Comment: what type of image? for cartoon-like gfx is  RLE and LZ for noisy and real world image is DCT/DFT like jpg better. what about lovering resolution ? Also what is too much time / resolution?